# NullReferenceException when using let in EF query syntax

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a query where if I use a `let` I get a `NullReferenceException` however if I use the same statement in the select it works fine.

```
var q = db.WorkOrders;
```

The following query throws an exception:

```
(from wo in q.OrderByDescending(x => x.WorkOrderNumber)
let cost = wo.Costs.Select(x => x.BaseCost + x.AdminOverhead + x.LabourOverhead).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()
select new ManageWorkOrderData
{
    Id = wo.Id,
    TotalCost = cost
}).ToListAsync();
```

However the following does not:

```
(from wo in q
select new ManageWorkOrderData
{
    Id = wo.Id,
    TotalCost = wo.Costs.Select(x => x.BaseCost + x.AdminOverhead + x.LabourOverhead).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()
}).ToListAsync();
```

Notice that in the second the subquery is the same, just not as a `let`.

**Update**
This question has been marked as a duplicate, however I don't agree as the code works fine when not used in the `let` part of the linq query. None of the types are nullable, and it's Entity Framework interpreting the code so I can't check for nulls.

There is no way to debug the code in VS as the code is all executed by Entity Framework/SQL. Interestingly the query isnt executed on the server, which leads me to believe its an EF issue. I'm interested to see if anyone else has any insight as to why EF throws an exception with the `let` and not when used in the select.

**Classes**

```
public class WorkOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public int WorkOrderNumber { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Cost> Costs { get; set; }

    public WorkOrder()
    {
        Costs = new HashSet<Cost>();
    }
}

public class Cost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int WorkOrderId { get; set; }
    public decimal BaseCost { get; set; }
    public decimal AdminOverhead { get; set; }
    public decimal LabourOverhead { get; set; }

    public virtual WorkOrder WorkOrder { get; set; }
}

public class ManageWorkOrderData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalCost { get; set; }
}
```

**Stack Trace**
Available from http://pastebin.com/uXkdM30A

Comment: This question shows no evidence of having debugged the problem, nor researched what could be causing the problem. If you feel that the extensive advice in the marked duplicate does not address your specific issue, please improve the question by providing [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, along with a more specific problem statement describing exactly where your exception occurs and why (including full stack trace).

Comment: This is not a normal NullReferenceException as the code is all done in linq. The duplicate linked answer does not address why the code would work when not placed in the `let`.

Comment: I understand that. But the fact that the answers don't _specifically_ address the LINQ scenario does not in and of itself mean that your question isn't a duplicate. If you want to assert it's not, you need to do enough work to demonstrate in your question that it's not. That means _at a minimum_ you must include the additional details I've mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: I can't repro this. Not in EF 6.1.3, not in 4.1.

Comment: Have you tried outputting the generated SQL in both instances?

Comment: @GertArnold I've included classes for use.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen the error occurs before the SQL query is executed, SQL Profiler isn't registering any queries.

Comment: As I say, I've solved the problem by not using a `let` but I am wondering why it would cause a problem

Comment: Would be interesting to see the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @GertArnold http://pastebin.com/uXkdM30A

Comment: I believe I've found the issue. It's more to do with the `OrderBy` than anything else. See https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1196

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an Entity Framework bug. This can be seen from the stack trace. This is an uncontrolled crash deep inside of EF. Microsoft classes never intentionally throw meaningless programmer error exceptions like NRE, ArrayIndexEx, DivByZeroEx, ...

Create a small, executable repro and report the bug on GitHub. The team is responsive.